# recommenderlab, Error in asMethod(object) : invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_geMatrix

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I am trying to change matrix into a structure that I can use in functions of the recommenderlab package.

```
datafile1 <- as(datafile1,"matrix")
datafile1
     name1 name2 rating1 rating2 rating3 rating4 rating5 rating6
[1,] "1"   "a"   "0"     "0"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "0"    
[2,] "2"   "d"   "0"     "0"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "0"    
[3,] "3"   "x"   "1"     "0"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "0"    
[4,] "4"   "b"   "0"     "1"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "0"  

library(recommenderlab)
datafile1 <- as(datafile1, "realRatingMatrix")
```

This is the result:

> Error in asMethod(object) : invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_geMatrix

Does anyone have an idea about what's going wrong here?

Comment: You need to post code that allows us to reproduce this error. You seem to have an object datafile1 which is throwing errors but we have no way to look at said object.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I hope my edit will help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the `RealRatingMatrix` class extends `Matrix`, and `Matrix` has not implemented matrices with `character`s in them. Convert your `matrix` to a `numeric` first, then convert.

```
# Recreate data
datafile1<-read.table(textConnection('
name1 name2 rating1 rating2 rating3 rating4 rating5 rating6
"1"   "a"   "0"     "0"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "0"    
"2"   "d"   "0"     "0"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "0"    
"3"   "x"   "1"     "0"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "0"    
"4"   "b"   "0"     "1"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "0"  
'),header=TRUE)
datafile1<-as.matrix(datafile1)

# Convert to numeric (by arbitrarily map the characters to numbers.)
datafile1<-sapply(data.frame(datafile1),as.numeric)

# Create real rating matrix
as(datafile1, "realRatingMatrix")
# 4 x 8 rating matrix of class ‘realRatingMatrix’ with 32 ratings.
```