# Undefined Columns Selected Error in data.frame

Tags: r, csv, recommendation-engine

Using the **recommenderlab** package on RStudio. Read the table from a .csv file and named the data.frame `Sweets`. Getting an error when using the `Recommender` command:

```
Sweets <- read.table(file.choose(), header = FALSE,sep=",", nrows = 17903)

> recommenderRegistry$get_entries(dataType = "realRatingMatrix")
$IBCF_realRatingMatrix
Recommender method: IBCF
Description: Recommender based on item-based collaborative filtering (real data).

> Recommender(Sweets[1:17903], method="IBCF")
Error in Recommender(Sweets[1:17903], method = "IBCF") : 
error in evaluating the argument 'data' in selecting a method for function 'Recommender':           
Error in `[.data.frame`(Sweets, 1:17903) : undefined columns selected
```

About Data:

```
ncol(Sweets)
[1] 3

nrow(Sweets)
[1] 17903

str(Sweets)
'data.frame':   17903 obs. of  3 variables:
$ V1: int  351 57 385 286 126 371 131 116 364 180 ...
$ V2: int  31 9 30 23 16 46 20 17 18 40 ...
$ V3: int  0 3 1 4 3 0 5 3 3 2 ...

head(Sweets)[, 1:3]
V1 V2 V3
1 351 31  0
2  57  9  3
3 385 30  1
4 286 23  4
5 126 16  3
6 371 46  0
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: Shouldn't be `Recommender(Sweets[1:17903, ], method="IBCF")`? You only have 3 columns in your data.frame and when writing `Sweets[1:17903]` R looks for 17903 columns and throws an error because there are only 3. I think you want 17903 data for all three columns, therefore you should write `Sweets[1:17903, ]` instead of `Sweets[1:17903]`.

Comment: @Jilber when putting Recommender(Sweets[1:17903, ], method="IBCF"), I got the following error, Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Recommender’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Comment: @Jilber I edited the command and got the following error again, > Recommender(Sweets[1:17903,3], method="IBCF")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Recommender’ for signature ‘"integer"’

Comment: I think you may need to convert your data.frame to a the class `realRatingMatrix`.  See [this post for a start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580506/r-recommenderlab-error-in-asmethodobject-invalid-class-na-to-dup-mmatrix) .

Comment: @aosmith The comment has three parts: recreate data, convert to numeric, and create real rating matrix. I edited the post and put the structure of the data.frame. I got an error when performing the third step.as(Sweets, "realRatingMatrix")
Error in as(Sweets, "realRatingMatrix") : 
  no method or default for coercing “matrix” to “realRatingMatrix”.

Comment: If I take the top six rows of your data.frame from your question, I can do `Sweets = as(Sweets, "realRatingMatrix")` and then `Recommender(Sweets, method = IBCF")` without any of the errors you mention.